# What is an easy way to store tweets into database?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, twitter, simplexml

I have a php function that retrieves tweets from Twitter & returns them in simplexml_load_string. I have to store those into database. Whats is an easy way to store those into database on page load? I have already tried my luck with ajax but json that is returned from twitter seems invalid. thanX a Lot in advance.

Comment: Will you ever need to do any filtering, like tweets by a particular user?

Comment: I mainly will be concerned with extracting values that its properties will contain like content, author name, message id etc. Yes, may be Filtering could be needed too.

Comment: how is json returned invalid? that doesn't seem to make sense. are you saying that twitter is returned badly formatted data? or is your software not interpreting it?  I work with twitter api a lot and haven't had such issue.

Comment: also, do you need to store all of the information? or just the tweet content and who tweeted it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply store them in the table as XML and then parse them on demand.

```
// perform query
$res = mysql_query('SELECT * from tweets');

// place xml objects into array
$tweets = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $tweets[] = new SimpleXMLElement($row['data']);
}
```

[SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Comment: is it possible that if I save tweets as xml into mysql & then extract data from those like I could like when in php. Say if $xml is xml object, I could run a loop on it to extract values from it like  "foreach ($xml->entry as $status) {echo status->content;}. I mean I could extract all its properties using mysql queries.

Comment: mysql functions will not return an xml object. The best approach is to store the xml text and then parse it into an xml object in the PHP code.

Comment: One addition in the OP is that the results are returned in simplexml_load_string from from the php function like "$xml = simplexml_load_string($result)". And now in php, i could get values of all properties of $xml. Is it like that I could store in database $xml object & then retreive from db & parse it in php. As at the end, I need all values that I could get when I use $xml object directly from php function.

Comment: You can serialize/unserialize objects and store them in the database if need be. http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: OK, thanX a Lot webbiedave for ur help.